# LNK Error while compiling rsa library

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

why am i getting this LNK error when trying to compile this rsa library:
http://www.efgh.com/software/rsa.txt
from
http://www.efgh.com/software/rsa.htm

```
mpuint.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl numeric_overflow(void)" (?numeric_overflow@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall mpuint::operator=(class mpuint const &)" (??4mpuint@@QAEXABV0@@Z)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add new function in MPUINT.CPP:

```
void numeric_overflow() {
    printf("Numeric overflow!");
}
```

Regards,

Trung,

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't specify a library file in your linker settings. A library file contains the actual definitions of the API's you are using in your code. In your example, you included a header file that somehow or somewhere declared a function with the following signature:

```
void __cdecl numeric_overflow(void)
```

But you didn't include the library that defines the function. The library is specified in the project settings -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies field in visual studio.

In that field you then specify the library file that corresponds to the function you used.

Comment: If this is insufficient, than you have to contact the author of the library you are using and ask him where he got it.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: this RSA library performance is not so well.
You can try other libraries (open source):

1. xInt (C++, easy to understand, fast, but this library is a part of Boost library): http://www.oakcircle.com/xint_docs/
2. BigDigits (C, lightweight, very fast): http://www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html
3. Crypto++ (C++, heavy, implement most crypto algorithms): http://www.cryptopp.com/

Regard,

Trung,